# $u_n$ is bounded in $L^1(\omega)$ implies $u_{n_{k}}$ weakly convergente in $L^2(\omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-convergence, weak-topology

I saw in a book that if $u_n$ is a bounded sequence in $L^1(\omega)$ then there exists a subsequence such that $u_{n_{k}}$ converge to some $u$ in $L^2(\omega)$, how it can be possible, we have not an injection of $L^1(\omega)$ in $L^2(\omega)$, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not missing some assumptions? I mean you are right, there is no such injections. For example pick
$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ as a constant sequence. Then you have
$$\int_0^1|f_n(x)|\, dx =[2\sqrt{x}]_0^1=2.$$
Therefore $f_n$ is bounded in $L^1([0,1])$, but
$$\int_0^1f_n^2\, dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\, dx=[\ln(x)]_0^1=\infty.$$
Hence $f_n\notin L^2([0,1])$. This means you cannot find any subsequence such that $f_n$ can converge in $L^2$.

Maybe you can give us the exact reference?

Comment: here is the reference, see equation 46 and 72, how he knew that the sequence $g(z_n)$ is bounded in $L^2$?

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12591-016-0339-1

Comment: I think the $L^2$ bounds come from the growth conditions (4) and (1), which basically mean $(g(s))^2 \leq C s^2$. Furthermore the $z_k$ seem to be a kind of Fourier approximation (see (37)) of a function $f$ in $L^2$, therefore $\|z_k\|_{L^2}\leq \|f\|_{L^2}$. Hence $\|g(z_k)\|_{L^2}\leq C\|z_k\|_{L^2}\leq \|f\|_{L^2}<\infty$..